# instantiating a generic referance class with data types known at runtime

Tags: c#, class, generics, reflection

I have  a generic class in C# which has 2 data types `public class ResolvedChainSubscriber < K, V>`, now I have to create an instance of this class, but the data type of one of the arguments will only be known at runtime. I have it stored as `Type Prototype`.

```
public static Object SubsciberTopic(Type ProtoType)
{
    Type[] type={Type.GetType("System.String"),ProtoType};
    Type resolve = typeof(ResolvedChainSubscriber <,>).MakeGenericType(type); 
    Object obj1=Activator.CreateInstance(resolve);              
}
```

However, i get the exception

> MissingMethodException: NO parameterless constructor defined for this object

Please note that the class `ResolvedChainSubscriber` is a reference class.. hence i cannot edit it to add a function or constructor

Comment: are u asking about dynamic datatype?

Comment: well, i'm saying that the type of the second data type, that is "V", will only be known at run time.... and it is stored in ProtoType

Comment: Issue here doesn't seems to be related to type resolution, which should happen at compile time for the generics, else you need reflection to resolve the type, check the links I have posted underneath, if they help

Answer (score 0):

Does `ResolvedChainSubscriber` have any public constructors? Try to use `Activator.CreateInstance` [overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that takes parameters for existing public constructor.

Comment: Do, i still need a constructor is i want to assign the value of another Object class object to obj1. for example if i have (Object object) in the parameters for subscriberTopic...... and i want to typecast this object and store it in obj1